# Subset selection with maximum sum and minimum variance?

Tags: optimization, np-hard, combinatorics, subset-sum

So I am trying to tackle a combinatorial optimization problem and would like some insights on how to approach it. The problem statement is as follows: Consider a set of elements of size **N**, how do I select a subset of size **k<N** such that the sum of the elements in the subset is maximum and variance among the elements is minimum. Lets consider an set of *10* integers: `[29, 63, 83, 50, 67, 45, 52, 66, 75, 13]` . Suppose I want to select a subset of *4* integers, then one possible solution can be `[67, 29, 63, 83]`. I obtained this solution by forming all possible subsets of length *4*. Then I calculated the variance and sum of each subset and chose the subset with minimum `variance/sum` ratio. Instead of brute-forcing it how can I solve the above mentioned problem efficiently?

Comment: Do you need to minimize $\frac {Var} {mean}$? In this case, your solution is not the best one: $[66, 67, 75, 83]$ is obviously better.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/47884/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/132431/755. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: You can't simultaneously maximize the sum and minimize the variance; it might be impossible to achieve both simultaneously.  If you actually want to minimize their ratio, please [edit] your question to state that, instead of claiming you're trying to minimize/maximize both of them.  The first step to solving a problem is to make sure you can state the problem clearly.  Are you looking for a theoretical solution with the best possible worst-case asymptotic running time, or a practical solution?